# Reinstalling provisioning profiles in XCode5

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode5, provisioning-profile

I recently was forced to reinstall XCode5 to correct a problem in with Interface Builder. The reinstall corrected the issue but erased my provisioning profiles and now I am unable to test apps on a physical device.

From others' suggestions, I went to Preferences > Accounts > View Details... and clicked the Refresh button at the bottom left of the resulting window.

When I plug in a physical device, XCode does not list it in the available devices. In Organizer, each device that I use (an iPad and iPhone) shows a valid profile when connected. Each valid profile shows the correction expiration date.

What steps am I missing to get these devices recognized by XCode?

Thanks!

Comment: Are your developer/distribution certificates installed correctly?

Comment: I'm assuming they are, since they were intact before the XCode reinstall. They are listed in Organizer and marked as valid. What else would I look for to determine their validity?

Comment: Did you set the provisioning profile of the app from `Your Project -> Build Settings -> Provisioning Profile` ?

Comment: The only thing I see in Build Settings that is related is Code Signing Identity. For Debug, I have tried setting it to my developer account, but it has no effect

Comment: I was wondering if I should remove the profiles from the device. I hesitate to do this out of fear of creating a much bigger nightmare than I already have

Comment: No need to remove the profiles from devices! See my answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the provisioning profile of your app.

As shown in the image below, it needs to be set from 2 places (1 and 2)

[image: Setting the provisioning profile]

Hope this helps!